# Dockerfile problem with Miniconda on ARM64 MacOS

Tags: docker, arm64, miniconda

I have a Dockerfile and want to install Miniconda using the following lines:

```
# installing conda
RUN wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-arm64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh && bash ~/miniconda.sh -b -p $HOME/miniconda3 -b
ENV PATH=/$HOME/miniconda3/bin:$PATH
RUN conda update -y conda \
    && rm miniconda.sh
```

However, this fails with the following error:

```
#14 0.802 2023-02-17 21:52:22 (67.5 MB/s) - '/root/miniconda.sh' saved [43758576/43758576]
#14 0.802 
#14 0.812 PREFIX=/root/miniconda3
#14 0.817 /root/miniconda.sh: line 313: md5: command not found
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-arm64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh && bash ~/miniconda.sh -b -p $HOME/miniconda3 -b]: exit code: 127
```

Apparently, `md5` is missing. I tried to add this via `brew` which seems to complete, but it then still fails with the md5 error.

```
# installing brew & md5sha1sum
RUN /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)" \
RUN brew install md5sha1sum
```

***UPDATE***

I changed the Dockerfile (making use of CMD instead of RUN and creating a symbolic link to md5) and now it works.

```
RUN wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-arm64.sh
CMD ["sudo ln -s md5sum /bin/md5"]
CMD ["chmod +x Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-arm64.sh"]
CMD ["./Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-arm64.sh -b -p $HOME/miniconda3 -b"]
ENV PATH=/$HOME/miniconda3/bin:$PATH
CMD ["conda update -y conda"]
RUN rm Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-arm64.sh
```